# upgrade Appium from 1.4.16 to 1.5.0

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, upgrade, appium

I am using **Appium1.4.16** in **Ubuntu14.04**.. There is a latest version of Appium been released.. So, I need to upgrade to latest version i.e, **Appium1.5.0**..

How can I do that ?

Will there be any problem if I try `npm install -g appium` without removing the older version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will replace old version.
But you can use command :

> npm -install -g appium@1.4.16

to install previous version.

Comment: I am running python tests on android app.. Tests are running randomly.. I want the test to run in a sequence.. like say, first it should check if the app is installed, then tests on actionbar, then test for buttons, etc etc..
 How can I do that ?

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to do it in python. In java we can use testNg and priority. Try search similar for python.

Comment: I changed the name of the tests.. and it worked..  
`def test_1_app_install` , `def test_2_action_bar`,  etc etc...